# spawn_link chaining other processes?

Tags: erlang

If process A spawn_link()'s process B and then process B spawn()'s process C, is the only way for process A to catch an error in process C if we replace "spawn()" for "spawn_link()" in process B?

I believe if this isn't replaced, process A will only know if process B dies?

Comment: Yes! there is no automatic linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When process B spawns process C, it basically forgets about it; in this case, if C is dying, process B will have no idea about it. If process B spawns process C using spawn_link, process C will be linked to B as child (C) - parent (B): if C dies, B will be notified and depending on the implementation, it can die (A will be notified) or survive further.